# SELECT em 2 tabelas MySql com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com uma duvida ao dar um select, pois  tenho 3 tabelas, são elas profissionais, experiencias, endereco.

Vamos dizer que tenho um profissional e esse profissional tem mais de 2 experiencias. Tem alguma forma de trazer em uma linha essas informações, se não como posso fazer isso em php, para que não se repita o nome do profissional.

Tabelas:

**Profissional:**

id

nome

sobrenome

estado_civil

**experiencias:**

id

cargo

dt_entrada

dt_saida

id_profissional

Meu select por enquanto é assim

```
SELECT pro.id, pro.nome, exp.cargo
FROM Profissional pro
INNER JOIN experiencias exp ON exp.id_profissional = pro.id
WHERE pro.id = :algumacoisa GROUP BY pro.id
```

Exemplo de saida

Temos 1 profissional com 2 cargos cadastrado.

```
ID             Nome                  Cargo           Cargo

1             romario            programador        Técnico
```

Mais ou menos assim, sei que o nome de tabela não se repete, mas se tiverem uma solução, agradeço.

Comment: Tentou usar inner join?

Comment: Você vai precisar usar tanto MySQL como PHP para fazer isso. Poste as estruturas das tabelas para te ajudarmos.

Comment: Pronto, consegui exemplificar mais um pouco a minha duvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Galera consegui resolver,
Bastava eu usar GROUP_CONCAT();

Ficou assim:

```
SELECT pro.id, pro.nome, GROUP_CONCAT(exp.cargo)
FROM Profissional pro
INNER JOIN experiencias exp ON exp.id_profissional = pro.id
WHERE pro.id = :algumacoisa GROUP BY pro.id
```

Ele traz todos os cargos desse usuário em uma linha só sem repetir o nome e separados com virgula.

Comment: Aqui deu certo também!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pro.id,pro.nome,exp.id,exp.nome
   FROM Profissional pro, experiencias exp 
WHERE exp.id = pro.id and pro.id = :algumacoisa
```

Comment: Disso eu já sei, ele repeti o nome para mostrar mais de uma experiencia.

Comment: da uma olhada aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603650/mysql-2-select-in-one-query

Comment: Ainda não tirou minha duvida!

Comment: O ideal é usar join pra "mesclar" as tabelas e mostrar tudo em uma.